# Checking positive definiteness

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Is the matrix $(A - D'AD)$ positive definite if the spectral radius of $D$, $\rho(D)<1$? Here $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix.

I want the matrix $(A - D'AD)$ to be positive definite using as fewer conditions as possible. If necessary, one can assume

1. $D'AD = DAD'$ and/or
2. $D'$ (not $D$) and $A$ commute.

Note: $D$ is not symmetric.

Comment: What do you get when $A$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix and $D=\pmatrix{2/3&1/3\\1/3&2/3}$?

Comment: In this case $\rho(D)$ is not less than $1$, right?

Comment: Sorry, I left out the scalar multiplier: the $2/3$ makes its radius equal to $1.$  It's an interesting boundary case.

Comment: Please see, $\rho(D)<1$. This implies $\rho(D) \neq 1$.

Comment: Right: that's what "boundary" means.  But at a minimum I think you need to assume $D$ is symmetric: there are easy counterexamples when it's not.

Comment: $D$ is not symmetric in my case. Will the assumption $D'AD = DAD'$ suffice? Can you prove $(A-D'AD)$ pd under this condition?

Comment: @Peter Flom The way this is written, combined with the history of comments, and topped-off by what my answer turned out to be, does not make this look like a self-study question. Rather, a "real life" question.

Comment: This is indeed a research problem. I want the matrix $(A-D'AD)$ to be positive definite using as fewer number of conditions as possible. Kindly let me know what makes you think that it is off-topic, @Peter. Your suggestion will be helpful in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false even if D is symmetric, as shown in the following 2 by 2 counterexample.

Here is the MATLAB output (disp means display, eig are the eigenvalues)

```
>> A = [1.3 -1;-1 1.3]
A =
    1.3000   -1.0000
   -1.0000    1.3000
>> D = [.1 -.2;-.2 -.6]
D =
    0.1000   -0.2000
   -0.2000   -0.6000
>> disp(eig(A))
    0.3000
    2.3000
>> disp(eig(D))
   -0.6531
    0.1531
>> disp(eig(A-D'*A*D))
   -0.0458
    2.2608
```

Edit: In response to edit of question:

Here is a counterexample in which D is not symmetric; D' and A commute (because A is (a scalar multiple of the) identity matrix).

```
>> A = eye(2)
A =
     1     0
     0     1
>> D = [-.1 -.5;-1 -.1]
D =
   -0.1000   -0.5000
   -1.0000   -0.1000
>> disp(eig(A))
     1
     1
>> disp(eig(D))
    0.6071
   -0.8071
>> disp(eig(A-D'*A*D))
   -0.0389
    0.7689
>> disp(D'*A-A*D')
     0     0
     0     0
```